# Is there a way to specify @JsonTypeIdResolver on mapper config instead of annotation?

Tags: jackson

Is there a way to specify @JsonTypeIdResolver on mapper config instead of annotating the target class ?
example, instead of :

```
@JsonTypeInfo(  
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM,  
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
    property = "@type") 
@JsonTypeIdResolver(FooTypeIdResolver.class)        
public class Foo {

}
```

Only have

```
@JsonTypeInfo(  
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM,  
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
    property = "@type") 
public class Foo {

}
```

And do something like the following on the mapper

```
mapper.getSerializationConfig()
.with(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector())
.without(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
...
// something like this :
.addTypeIdResolver(Foo.class, FooTypeIdResolver.class)
```

I am asking this because the FooTypeIdResolver is on a different "library" which the Foo library cannot depend on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Jackson's [mix-in annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations), in your case you would first create a class with the annotations you want to add:

```
@JsonTypeIdResolver(FooTypeIdResolver.class)
private static class FooMixIn {

}
```

And then you would apply this mix-in to the Foo class (roughly speaking this takes annotations present on `FooMixIn` and applies them to `Foo`)

```
mapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Foo.class, FooMixIn.class);
mapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Foo.class, FooMixIn.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

Handling of all annotations can be overridden by defining custom `AnnotationIntrospector`: usually by extending default `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`. This can then use any alternate data source you want.

Mix-in annotations are the other obvious way to go, as explained in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative