# Jackon JSON: Polymorphic deseralization when subclasses are unknown

Tags: jackson

I'm trying to do some polymorphic deseralization of JSON using Jackson, however the list of subclasses is unknown at compile time, so I can't use a @JsonSubtype annotation on the base class.
Instead I want to use a TypeIdResolver class to perform the conversion to and from a property value.

The list of possible subclasses I might encounter will be dynamic, but they are all registered at run time with a registry. So I would appear to need my TypeIdResolver object to have a reference to that registry class. It has to operate in what is essentially a dependency injection environment (i.e I can't have a singleton class that the TypeIdResolver consults), so I think I need to inject the registry class into the TypeIdResolver. The kind of code I *think* I want write is:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.something(new MyTypeIdResolver(subclassRegistry));
mapper.readValue(...)
```

However, I can't find a way of doing the bit in the middle. The only methods I can find use java annotations to specify what the TypeIdResolver is going to be.

This question [Is there a way to specify @JsonTypeIdResolver on mapper config instead of annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050818/is-there-a-way-to-specify-jsontypeidresolver-on-mapper-config-instead-of-annota) is the same, though the motivation is different, and the answer is to use an annotation mixin, which won't work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in the end what I did was abandon Jackson and write my own much simpler framework based on javax.json that just did the kinds of serialisation I wanted in a much more straightforward fashion. I was only dealing with simple DTO (data transfer object) classes, so it was just much simpler to write my own simple framework.

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleModule` has method `registerSubtypes()`, with which you can register subtypes. If only passing `Class`es, simple class name is used as type id, but you can also pass `NamedType` to define type id to use for sub-class.

So, if you do know full set, just build `SimpleModule`, register that to mapper.

Otherwise if this does not work you may need to resort to just sharing data via static singleton instance (if applicable), or even `ThreadLocal`.